# Access underlying DbContext (or run stored procedure) from Entity Framework POCO method

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is it possible to access the underlying DbContext (the DbContext that has populated this object/has this object in its cache/is tracking this object) from inside a model object, and if so, how?

The best answer I have found so far is [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/08/tip-24-how-to-get-the-objectcontext-from-an-entity.aspx) which is five years old. Is it still the best solution available?

I’m using the latest version of Entity Framework if that matters.

---

Here's a sample to clarify my question:

I have a hierarchical tree. Let’s say it is categories that could have sub-categories. The model object would be something like this:

```
class Category
{
    string CategoryId { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }

    virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if I want to access all descendants of a category (not just its immediate children) I can use a recursive query like this:

```
class Category
{
    //...

    IEnumerable<Category> Descendants
    {
        get
        {
            return Children.Union(Children.SelectMany(q => q.Descendants));
        }
    }
}
```

which works, but has bad performance (due to multiple database queries it needs to perform).

But suppose I have an optimized query that I can run to find descendent (maybe I store my primary key in a way that already contains path, or maybe I’m using SQL Server data type *hierarchyid*, etc.). How can I run such a query, which needs access to the whole table/database and not just the records available through model object’s navigational properties?

This can be either done by running a stored procedure/SQL command on the database, or a query like this:

```
class Category
{
    //...

    IEnumerable<Category> Descendants
    {
        get
        {
            // this won't work, because underlying DbContext is not available in this context!
            return myDbContext.Categories.Where(q => q.CategoryId.StartsWith(this.CategoryId));
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way at all to implement such a method?

Comment: I think you are looking for efficient way for querying self referencing tree structure, am I right ?

Comment: @MohsenEsmailpour, I'm not looking for the efficient query itself, but a way to implement it as an EF model object's property/method without the need to pass DbContext instance to the method.

Comment: I think it's not good idea pass `EF Context` into model for querying data.

Comment: @MohsenEsmailpour, I know, it creates dependence on EF inside the (otherwise platform-agnostic) POCO, but any alternative would create such implementation dependence anyway (at least the alternatives I can think of do).